# Merge array into a new array javascript in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, loops

Hi all i have this loop which will loop 4 times.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  var d = [[1111,2222],[3333,4444]]
}
```

below is my expect output , thank you every much all.

```js
var expected = [ 
 [
   [1111,2222],[3333,4444]
 ], 
 [
   [1111,2222],[3333,4444]
 ], 
 [
   [1111,2222],[3333,4444]
 ], 
 [
   [1111,2222],[3333,4444]
 ]
]
```

Comment: What issue are you having? So far you have only given an input and expected output. Please don’t expect us to write the code for you

Comment: Expected output already displayed. He expect the `var expected`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you tried to achieve?

```
const output = [];
const input = [[1111,2222],[3333,4444]]
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  output.push(input)
}
console.log(output) // [[[1111,2222],[3333,4444]], [[1111,2222],[3333,4444]], [[1111,2222],[3333,4444]], [[1111,2222],[3333,4444]]]
```

Comment: Please wait for the OP to update their question. As future updates may make this irrelevant

Answer (score 2):

You can get the result like this

```
    function getNewArray() {
        var newArray = []
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            var d = [[1111,2222],[3333,4444]]
            newArray.push(d)
        }
        return newArray;
    }
    
    let expected = getNewArray()
```

Comment: Please wait for the asker to update their question. As future updates may make this irrelevant

Comment: This is good but nothing will output. You need to add `let expected = getNewArray()` 